# Avoiding high CPU usage with NIO

Tags: java, network-programming, cpu-usage

I wrote a multithreaded gameserver application which handles multiple simultaneous connections using [NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html). Unfortunately this server generates full CPU load on one core as soon as the first user connects, even when that user is not actually sending or receiving any data.

Below is the code of my network handling thread (abbreviated to the essential parts for readability). The class `ClientHandler` is my own class which does the network abstraction for the game mechanics. All other classes in the example below are from `java.nio`.

As you can see it uses a `while(true)` loop. My theory about it is that when a key is writable, `selector.select()` will return immediately and `clientHandler.writeToChannel()` is called. But when the handler returns without writing anything, the key will stay writable. Then select is called again immediately and returns immediately. So I got a busy spin.

**Is there a way to design the network handling loop in a way that it sleeps as long as there is no data to send by the clientHandlers?** Note that low latency is critical for my use-case, so I can not just let it sleep an arbitrary number of ms when no handlers have data.

```
ServerSocketChannel server = ServerSocketChannel.open();
server.configureBlocking(false);
server.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
Selector selector = Selector.open();
server.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
// wait for connections

while(true)
{
     // Wait for next set of client connections
    selector.select();
    Set<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys();
    Iterator<SelectionKey> i = keys.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = i.next();
        i.remove();

        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
            SocketChannel clientChannel = server.accept();
            clientChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            clientChannel.socket().setTcpNoDelay(true);
            clientChannel.socket().setTrafficClass(IPTOS_LOWDELAY);
            SelectionKey clientKey = clientChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
            ClientHandler clientHanlder = new ClientHandler(clientChannel);
            clientKey.attach(clientHandler);
        }
        if (key.isReadable()) {
            // get connection handler for this key and tell it to process data 
            ClientHandler clientHandler = (ClientHandler) key.attachment();
            clientHandler.readFromChannel();
        }
        if (key.isWritable()) {
            // get connection handler and tell it to send any data it has cached 
            ClientHandler clientHandler = (ClientHandler) key.attachment();
            clientHandler.writeToChannel();
        }
        if (!key.isValid()) {
            ClientHandler clientHandler = (ClientHandler) key.attachment();
            clientHandler.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `select()`/NIO is all that useful to wait on when channels are *writable* - the OS network buffer should be able to take care of that. If your bottleneck is whether data is available to be written, you should wait on that. (I.e. on your `ClientHandler`s I suppose.)

Comment: I would consider using a framework to support NIO like netty or mina.  These have most of the bugs already solved.  If you have less than 1000 connections, you could use blocking IO or NIO instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any reason why the reading and writing must happen with the same selector. I would use one selector in a thread for read/accept operations and it will always be blocking until new data arrives.

Then, use a separate thread and selector for writing. You mention you are using a cache to store messages before they are sent on the writable channels. In practice the only time a channel would not be writable is if the kernel's buffer is full, so it will rarely not be writable. A good way to implement this would be to have a dedicated writer thread that is given messages, and sleeping; it can be either `interrupt()`ed when new messages should be sent, or using a `take()` on a blocking queue. Whenever a new message arrives, it will unblock, do a `select()` on all writable keys and send any pending messages; only in rare cases will a message have to remain in the cache since a channel is not writable.

Comment: Why the dedicated writer thread? It won't block, so you don't need a separate thread.

Answer (score 8):

```
SelectionKey clientKey = clientChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
```

The problem is here. SocketChannels are almost always writable, unless the socket send buffer is full. Ergo they should normally not be registered for `OP_WRITE:` otherwise your selector loop will spin. They should only be so registered if:

1. there is something to write, and
2. a prior `write()` has returned zero.

Comment: So does this mean I can resister and unregister OP_WRITE as required?

Comment: @mal Of course. That's what you *have* to do.

Comment: Ok, this is question is fuzz , I will open new post for detial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67697853/nio-selector-howto-achive-active-send-message-without-spin